# How to copy all attached Listeners to new Node in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, listener

I have an `ObservableList<DataClass> someData` with a ChangeListener attached to it (via `addListener`). That List is updated by a background thread from time to time. Actually not the List itself is updated but the new List, returned by the thread, is saved in the member `someData`:

```
...
task.onSuccess(event -> setSomeData(task.getValue());
...
// standard setter generated by IntelliJ
public void setSomeData(ObservableList<DataClass> someData) { 
   this.someData = someData;
}
```

Now when I set `someData` using the standard setter the data itself is in the new List, okay, but also all the Listeners which were attached to the old List are gone. I don't want to copy the whole List to my old List because it could have tons of elements.

I know I could save the Listeners as member variables and reassign them to the new List but that would have clumped up the code and needed some hardcoding in the setter method (since there is no `#getListeners` method in `ObservableList`). [edit: Actually I can't do that because the listener is added by another class which I can't/don't want to access from this class.]

**How can I set the new List preserving the Listeners and without copying every element?**

I'm on the newest version of Java.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information the best approach seems to be using a `ListProperty`. It's a `Property<ObservableList<ItemType>>`, but also implements `ObservableList<ItemType>` (the content being the content of the list wrapped by the property).

Using this class allows you to add the listeners to the `ListProperty`, but still keep the code for replacing the data simple:

```
private final ListProperty<DataClass> someData = new SimpleListProperty<>();

public void setSomeData(ObservableList<DataClass> someData) { 
   this.someData.set(someData);
}

...

this.someData.addListener(someListener);
```

Comment: hmm but wouldn't that have the same effect as `this.someData.clear(); this.someData.addAll(someData)`, copying every element?

Comment: @LPrc not quite. If you call `clear` and call `addAll`, you're triggering 2 changes, with `ListProperty.set` you only trigger a single change. This change is probably to the one triggered by `setAll`. Note however that your options are limited by the design choices you've made (other class determines `ObservableList` implementation; listeners should be kept...), but with this approach you still have the `ObservableList` as backing list instead of simply copying the content...

Answer (score 2):

Don't erase the reference, just erase its content

```
task.onSuccess(event -> someData.setAll(task.getValue()));
```